# Django admin display the instances of a model filtered by a field

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I would like to provide a view in the django admin based on a model but filtered on a criteria.

Here for example the updated date , like that the user can rack the changes made on the model.

I have admin.py where I register the ModelAdmin but how I need to proceed:

- create a new ModelAdmin with a list filter?
- extend the template change_list.html or create a new one

I would like that the user would be able to select a date to track the instance of the model have been changed.

Thank in advance for any link, lesson, example speaking about that. I found the only basic example how to play with the admin.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is ..in your apps *admin.py*

```
from app.models import YourModel
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
....list_display = ("field1","field2","updated","timestamp")
....list_filter = ("updated","timestamp") 
....class Meta:
........model= YourModel
admin.site.register(YourModel,YourModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But how to open directly this page from the index.html by a link?

I see the link when you click on a model defined as following in index.html :

   <th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }}</a></th>
I see the url for the filter:

/admin/MyApp/MyModel/?updated__gte=2018-05-18+00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&updated_It=2018-05-19+00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00

Is it possible for me to define extra action from the index.html like provide the filter view with pass paremeter?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. But how to open directly this page from the index.html by a link?

I see the link when you click on a model defined as following in index.html :

```
<th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }}</a></th>
```

I see the url for the filter:

```
/admin/MyApp/MyModel/?updated__gte=2018-05-18+00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&updated_It=2018-05-19+00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00
```

Is it possible for me to define extra action from the index.html like provide the filter view with pass paremeter?